# Adding downloaded file to history

Tags: php, history, download

My problem is:
I have some script that is displaying some file. I want to add feature that after downloading this file it is automatically added to history. Where i can download it from there again.
This is code that is displaying my pdf file:

```
$model = $this->loadModel($id);
if (! $model->isStatus(LoanStatus::STATUS_CURRENT)) {
    Report::set(Report::ERROR, Yii::t('app', 'Monits a avilable only for current loans'));
    $this->redirect($this->createUrl('loan/view', ['id'=>$model->primaryKey]));
}
$monitBase64 = $model->getMonit($model->client);
if ($monitBase64 === null) {
    Report::set(Report::ERROR, Yii::t('app', 'There is no monits for this client'));
    $this->redirect($this->getId());
}
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
echo base64_decode($monitBase64);
Yii::app()->end();
```

At the moment i can only add this file to a history manually.
My history looks like that:

```
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <?php echo $form->dateField($model, 'date', ['class' => 'form-control btn-rect', 'placeholder' => 'YYYY-MM-DD']); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'date'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'description', ['class' => 'form-control btn-rect', 'placeholder' => 'Opis']); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'description'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'file', ['class' => 'form-control btn-rect', 'placeholder' => 'Plik']); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'file'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <?php echo GxHtml::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'), array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-rect pull-right'));?>
    </div>
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>




  <?php if ($files !== null) { ?>
                <?php foreach ($files as $file) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $file->date; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $file->description; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $file->file; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="<?= $this->createUrl('/loanFile/download/id/' . $file->primaryKey); ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-info btn-rect">Pobierz</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
```

Everything in this code is dont manually. I chose date manually, description and file as well. What should i do to add file to history after downloading it. For without description and date i just want to understand how should it be done. Any suggestions?

Comment: What history are you talking about? The browser's download history?

Comment: I mean history made in application. Now i must first download file, then add it manually to the history in this case it's 2th and 3th block of code, after sentece: My history looks like that

Comment: You made your own history feature, but you don't know how to add an item to it?

Comment: I didn't create it. Im new employee is larger project.

Comment: Well I have no idea how your history feature works. I know much less about your particular codebase than you do, even if you _are_ a new employee. Why don't you ask your co-workers?